# Using macros as functions

Tags: common-lisp

I'm new to Common Lisp, so this got me a bit stumped and Google has failed me.

I have a function `sizzle` defined like

```
(defun sizzle (f &rest r) ...blah blah...)
```

And now I just need to check if all optional arguments are non-nil, so naturally I did

```
(apply #'and r)
```

...and then it turns out that `and` isn't a function, it's a macro (which I haven't got around to just yet).

So, my question is, is there a way to use macros as functions (much like above), or should I just make my own function to check if all values is a given list are non-nil? Or is there yet another approach I haven't thought of?

Comment: The OP is asking whether one can use macros like functions. (And the answer is "no".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use macros as functions (that's why it's better to make some things functions, and that's why compiler macros instead of regular macros are used for optimization).

I would use `(every #'identity r)` or `(notany #'null r)` instead of writing my own `AND` function for your example.